# Non vanishing vector field on torus in the form of $ad_X (Y)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Assume that $X$ is a non vanishing vector field on torus $\mathbb{T}^2$.
Is there a vector field $Y$  such that $[X,Y]$ does not vanish on torus?

What about if we replace torus by an arbitrary compact manifold of zero Euler characteristic?

Answer (score 2):

If I may assume $X$ to be expressible in a *global* coordinate system $\{x^1,x^2\}$  in which $X=\partial_1$ , (this is always possible *locally* as $X$ is non-vanishing) the answer to the first question is yes . For $Y = Y^1\partial_1+Y^2\partial_2$ to be a required field, one only needs to ensure that not both $\partial_1(Y^i)$ vanish simultaneously. For instance, let $Y=cos(x^1)\partial_1+sin(x^1)\partial_2$. As for the second question, the unit circle $S^1$ looks like a counter-example to me.